# How to remove bitmap image on click from canvas

Tags: javascript, bitmap, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am using createjs as my framework. I've placed a Bitmap on the canvas and I created a function to try and remove it but I keep getting an error message in the console that image is not defined. This is what my code looks like:

```
// onload=init() called in html doc
function init(){

var canvas = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

// Add image to canvas
image = new createjs.Bitmap("image.png");
image.x = 200;
image.y = 180;
image.scaleX = 0.35;
image.scaleY = 0.35;
canvas.addChild(image);

image.addEventListener('click', pop);

canvas.update();
}

//remove image from canvas
function pop() {
console.log('pop');
canvas.removeChild(image);
}
```

When I click on it, I get the console message "pop" followed by the error I mentioned above. I've tried moving the function inside init but I appear to get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make image as global variable, so that it can be accessed by all the functions in your case function `pop`.

```
 var image;// defining 'image' variable as global
 function init(){

    var canvas = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

   // Add image to canvas
   image = new createjs.Bitmap("image.png");
   image.x = 200;
   image.y = 180;
   image.scaleX = 0.35;
   image.scaleY = 0.35;
   canvas.addChild(image);

   image.addEventListener('click', pop);

   canvas.update();
```

}

```
//remove image from canvas
function pop() {
  console.log('pop');
  canvas.removeChild(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. You defined `image` inside your `init` function, so it is not accessible on the `pop` method.

There are two easy fixes. Either move the `var image` outside of the init function, or use the click target instead.

```
var image;
function init() {
  init = new createjs.Bitmap();
  // etc
}

// OR

function pop(event) {
  stage.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

Scope is really important to understand when building JavaScript applications, so I suggest getting to know it a little better :)

Cheers,