# remove canvas object mouseclick event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been working on a JS based game where multiple balls are falling. Those are JS canvas objects. What I want to do now is to when a user clicks on a ball, the ball should vanish or disappear. I am very new to JS and I don't know yet how to do that. Can anyone suggest me how should I achieve my desired output.

I had a survey on this and found this snippet as an inspiration.

```js
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.round(min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
class Ball {
  static get colors() {
    return [
      'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'gold', 'purple', 'darkRed'
    ];
  }
  constructor() {
    this.radius = random(12.5, 20);
    this.x = random(this.radius - 10, width);
    this.y = -this.radius;
    this.speed = random(2, 4);
    this.color = Ball.colors[random(0, Ball.colors.length - 1)];

  }
}
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  width = canvas.width,
  height = canvas.height;

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);

resizeCanvas();
let balls = [];
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

setInterval(() => {
  balls.push(new Ball());
}, random(50, 200));

requestAnimationFrame(function game() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    let ball = balls[i];
    ball.y += ball.speed;
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(game);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* to remove the top and left whitespace */
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* just to be sure these are full screen*/
    
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
    /* To remove the scrollbars */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Agree with above comment. Just to get you going, you will need to track your mouse position on the screen.

Comment: @mplungjan your [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173143/how-to-remove-bitmap-image-on-click-from-canvas) had nothing to do with the question at hand...

Comment: Close enough so just for completeness’ sake

Comment: Not close at all no, there the question was about createjs [canvas], which is not an HTML <canvas> and even less the 2DContext API OP is using here. `canvas.removeChild` won't do anything good to our OP.